# What is the return value of Connection.ping() in cx_oracle?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I've just installed a python package：[cx_oracle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/). From [the cx_oracle document](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html) I found a method: `Connection.ping()`, which is described as "Ping the server which can be used to test if the connection is still active.".

But the document doesn't mentioned what is the return value of `ping()`.

I wrote some code to do a test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("...")
print(conn.ping()) # display：None
conn.close()
print(conn.ping()) # raise exception: cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not connected
```

From the test result, I found the `ping()` will return `None` if the connection is OK or raise an exception: `cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not connected` after the connection is closed.

Is there any other possible return values? Why not just return True or False?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [cx_Oracle documentation states that](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html) this is:

> This method is an extension to the DB API definition and is only available in Oracle 10g R2 and higher.

However, this method isn't documented in PEP 249 - the current Python Database API specification in either the [connection methods](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#connection-methods) or [optional extensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#optional-db-api-extensions) (or anywhere else for that matter).

The MySQL implementation of PEP 249 also [has this method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-ping.html); the documentation states that:

> When the connection is not available, an `InterfaceError` is raised. Use
>   the `is_connected()` method to check the connection without raising an
>   error.
>
> Raises `InterfaceError` on errors.

As this is identical to the cx_Oracle behaviour I would assume that this is the answer to your question and what you've determined the behaviour to be is correct:

- There is no return if the connection is active
- An `InterfaceError` is raised if the connection is not active

If we look at [the code for `.ping()`](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_oracle/src/1a6c77089c453202cd687de7a5c8cb06aca4c35d/Connection.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), it confirms that this is the manner in which the method has been implemented:

```c
static PyObject *Connection_Ping(
    udt_Connection *self,               // connection
    PyObject* args)                     // arguments
{
    sword status;

    if (Connection_IsConnected(self) < 0)
        return NULL;
    status = OCIPing(self->handle, self->environment->errorHandle,
            OCI_DEFAULT);
    if (Environment_CheckForError(self->environment, status,
            "Connection_Ping()") < 0)
        return NULL;
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}
```

Comment: MySQL also mentions this one: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-is-connected.html

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Ben's answer, given a `connectionObject` from the `cx_Oracle` library, this should at least incapsulate what you might want.

```
def isOpen(connectionObject):
    try:
        return connectionObject.ping() is None
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: If `ping` returns `None` the connection is still active else it returns an error like `cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-03135: connection lost contact`

Comment: @Superdooperhero how can it be returning a value if it's also raising an exception at the same time?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis note the `else`

Comment: So do you mean there are three outcomes? None for active, some error for failed (say timeout) and exception for closed (when manually closed or never opened in the first place)?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis There are either two outcomes as @Superdooperhero has described.  If the connection is active, `connectionObject.ping()` returns `None`, and thus `isOpen` returns `True`.  If the connection is not active, `connectionObject.ping()` throws an error.  The try/except catches the thrown error and thus `isOpen` returns `False`, which implies the connection is closed.

Comment: ah, sorry, thought at first that you were speaking about ping, not the snippet in this answer

Comment: problem is what happens when you don't have high enough version of db to support the ping command. Will the above code result in false? If so, it's problematic to use.